# @Temporal DATE and Oracle issue

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

We have two servers (WebLogic 12.1.2.0.0), each of them running the same application and connected to its own database. The server 1 has Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition 11.2.0.1.0 and Java 7, the server 2 has Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition  11.2.0.4.0 and Java 8.

In both cases the application uses:

- hibernate-core 3.6.9
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1
- hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0

In one of our classes we have the following annotations (Date is `java.util.Date`) :

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "creationDate", nullable = false, length = 7)
public Date getCreationDate() {
    return this.creationDate;
}
```

In case of the Server 1, the date is correctly stored and retrieved from the database - with time always equal 00:00:00. In case of the server 2 the date is stored with time.

For our application it is crucial to store the date with time set to 00:00:00 (so, basically, removed). We can create some workarounds for this problem, but still are not able to understand the reason for this behavior. Could you please explain?

Comment: i wonder what the database type is for this column? Putting length on a DATE column would be sort of pointless.

Comment: Check version of JDBC drivers used. There were some nuances changed in newest ones.

Comment: How the date is inserted is probably more relevant. Also via a JPA operation?

Comment: @NeilStockton the database column is DATE

Comment: so where is your DEBUGGING? Look at the SQL statements to INSERT into these databases.

Comment: @Deanna, were you able to solve this issue? I am also having same with my application?

Comment: @Deanna we are having this exact problem as well, were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @Scott I found some articles about incompatibilities of JDBC drivers, but we were still not sure that it was exact that problem. In the end we stayed with a workaround, as it was a quick solution that we desperately needed. Sorry!

Comment: @user3181365 please see my reply to Scott.

Comment: It seems that it is a problem with combination of weblogic and jdk 8, because we have faced the same problem, but when I run the application with Tomcat and JDK 8, @Temporal(DATE) works like a charm.

Comment: I believe the problem is a `ClassLoader` issue, for finding `javax.persistence.Temporal` annotation, and the one inside the project libs has conflicts with the one bundled in Weblogic itself. I've added `javax.persistence` package to `prefer-application-packages` of `weblogic.xml`, but problem still exists.